# rails delete a record with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to use `.find` or `.where` to find a certain record in my database to delete, but I'm having trouble...

I have this in my routes

```
resources :objects do
  delete 'item' => 'objects#item_destroy', :as => :item_destroy
end
```

In my controller

```
def item_destroy
  @object = Object.find(params[:object_id])
  @puser = Puser.find_by_user_id(current_user)
  if @mine = Mine.where(:puser_id => @puser).where(:object_id => @object)
    @mine.destroy
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { redirect_to :back } 
      format.xml { head :ok } 
    end
  end
end
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

My link to destroy is this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete me", object_item_destroy_path, method: :delete, :class => "pure-button pure-button-primary" %>
```

Can someone assist me?

Thanks!

EDIT::

also, when I'm only getting these parameters:

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"fdsagfHFUWlfiwoqobGBW92&9",
 "object_id"=>"21"}
```

I'm not getting `puser_id`?

Comment: can you post the trace of the error you're getting? Like where you're getting this: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`, line number, file, etc?

Comment: @Surya the error is on this line: `@mine.destroy` but here's the text of the error: `app/controllers/object_controller.rb:126:in 'item_destroy'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete me", object_item_destroy_path(object_id: @object), method: :delete, :class => "pure-button pure-button-primary" %>
```

**UPDATE:**

Change you objects_controller.rb file's method:

```
def item_destroy
  @object = Object.find(params[:object_id])
  @puser = Puser.find_by_user_id(current_user)
  if @mine = Mine.where(:puser_id => @puser).where(:object_id => @object).first
    @mine.destroy
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { redirect_to :back } 
      format.xml { head :ok } 
    end
  end
end
```

Here, when you say: `Mine.where(:puser_id => @puser).where(:object_id => @object)`, it will give you an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not the `Mine's` object, and hence `destroy` method is not available the way you're trying to invoke it.

I also encourage you to use associations here. Like:

```
@puser.mines.where(:object_id => @object).first
# or
@puser.mines.find_by_object_id(@object)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= link_to "Delete me", object_item_destroy_path**(:id => "something" or the object you want to delete)**, method: :delete, :class => "pure-button pure-button-primary" %>
```

Yup, no id is being passed in because no id is being put into the link.

Comment: Okay, got my parameters, but I'm still getting `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error

Comment: Ok, are you able to find out which method isn't getting its argument?